# How count rows by specific year and month, and draw on the bar graph with use seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have table(in .csv file):

```
id     date
1      20-04-2016
2      16-06-2017
3      04-12-2016
4      01-06-2017
5      01-09-2015
6      08-04-2016
```

I want count rows by `year = '2016', month = '04'` and `year = '2017', month = '06'`
It must be like:

```
count     date
2      04-2016
2      06-2017
```

And how I can draw bar graph with use counts in result?

Comment: I recommend setting your date as index as pandas has some really useful functions for a DateTime index.

Then you can select dates like `df['2016-04']` or slice it.

For plotting a bar graph on seaborn use the documentation https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Answer (score -1):

an old fashion way of solving it:

```
counter2016=0
counter2017=0
with open('C:/t.txt') as readObj:
    lines=readObj.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')
        if(line[-7:]=='04-2016'):
            counter2016 +=1
        elif(line[-7:]=='06-2017'):
            counter2017 +=1
        else:
            pass
x=['2016','2017']
y=[counter2016,counter2017]
sns.barplot(x,y)
plt.show()
```